# iPhone app release, how to exclude iphone4?

Tags: iphone, app-store, publish, iphone-4

Is it possible to publish an app that wont be available to iPhone 4?

I don't want any iphone4 to see the app inside the AppStore, or at least app store has to reject the purchase.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Would you mind sharing why you would want this? I'm really curious about why you'd rule out such a successful device.

Comment: I don't like the noise cancellation microphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include or exclude specific devices. I can't think of any use-case whether that would be desirable so I'm curious to know what yours is!

What you can do is say which features are required. For example, you can say that you need a camera, GPS, WiFi, etc. To do that you need to add the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` entry to your Info.plist. It's documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1).

Comment: +1 As Stephen points out, you can only specify capabilities required. Because the iPhone 4 has every capability of every iPhone yet released, you can't use that capability requirement to rule out the iPhone 4.

Comment: ok, i know this is the official answer, I was wondering if did exists a trick or a workaround

Comment: Your app doesn't really have any control over the purchase process other than what's presented in the Info.plist. _Technically_ you'd have more control if you implemented it using In App Purchase but that feels like the kind of thing that Apple would reject.